# Clang Static Analyzer - Extending

Tags: clang-static-analyzer

I am new to using Clang and wanted to understand if it was possible to extend the existing functionality of the static code analyzer. Basically for now I want to add a check that will analyze code and look for certain calls to see file system access in objective c code. I want it to integrate and output the findings into the existing static analysis report that Clang produces. Is this something that can be done in Clang? I know there are easier ways to do it by writing scripts (python,etc.) to parse the source code, but I want to see if this can be done with the existing Clang stuff. I did see the libClang library that might be able to accomplish this, but it seems that will not integrate into the static analysis findings report and is different.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Parsing source code with "scripting" languages usually leads to inaccurate results; ObjectiveC/C99/C are really lots more complicated than you think.  Stick to using a tool that knows how to parse the language, such as Clang.